# Identification of some sequence spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $p \in [1 , \infty)$. By definition, we know that
\begin{equation}
{\ell}^p = \left\{{\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} : \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {|a_n|}^p < \infty\right\} \mbox{ and } {\ell}^{\infty} = \{{\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} : {\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mbox{ is a bounded sequence}\}
\end{equation}
and also we can consider the space
\begin{equation}
c_{0 0} = \{{\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} : \mbox{ exists } n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \mbox{ such that } a_n = 0 \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \mbox{ with } n \geq n_0\}\mbox{.}
\end{equation}
Now, let $(X , \mathcal{M} , \mu)$ a measure space. Equally, by definition, we know that
\begin{equation}
L^p = \left\{f : X \to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ (or } \mathbb{C}\mbox{)}, \int_X {|f|}^p d \mu < \infty\right\} \mbox{ and } L^{\infty} = \{f : X \to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ (or } \mathbb{C}\mbox{)}, f \mbox{ is esentially bounded}\}
\end{equation}
and also we can consider the space
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{S} = \{\varphi : X \to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ (or } \mathbb{C}\mbox{)}, \varphi \mbox{ is simple, measurable and such that } \mu(sop \varphi) < \infty\}\mbox{.}
\end{equation}
Then, without much difficulty, we can show that ${\ell}^p = L^p$, ${\ell}^{\infty} = L^{\infty}$ and $c_{0 0} = \mathscr{S}$ if we consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N} , \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) , \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counter measure on $(\mathbb{N} , \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$, instead of an other abstract measure space $(X , \mathcal{M} , \mu)$. Let's show here for example the proof of ${\ell}^p = L^p$ with $(\mathbb{N} , \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) , \mu)$ in the example of footnote in case of somebody want to see it. But now, we continue to consider other two sequence spaces:
\begin{equation}
c = \{{\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} : {\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mbox{ is a convergent sequence}\} \mbox{ and } c_0 = \{{\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} : {\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mbox{ converges to } 0\}\mbox{.}
\end{equation}
If I have an abstract measure space $(X , \mathcal{M} , \mu)$, can I find two function spaces $T_1$ and $T_2$ on $(X , \mathcal{M} , \mu)$ such that $T_1 = c$ and $T_2 = c_0$ if I consider in particular the measure space $(\mathbb{N} , \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) , \mu)$?

Example.

We consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N} , \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) , \mu)$, where $\mu : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to [0 , + \infty]$ is the counter measure on $(\mathbb{N} , \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$. Let ${\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of real (or complex) numbers. One hand, let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) a non-negative function, which implies, considering the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, that $f$ is a measurable function and we suppose that $f(n) = a_n$ for all $n = 1 , 2 , \ldots$. Let $p \in [1 , \infty)$. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}} {|f|}^p d \mu = \int_{\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \{n\}} {|f|}^p d \mu = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{\{n\}} {|f|}^p d \mu = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{N}} \left({|f|}^p {\chi}_{\{n\}}\right) d \mu\mbox{.}
$$
The other hand, given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, ${|f|}^p {\chi}_{\{n\}} : \mathbb{N} \to [0 , \infty)$ is
$$
({|f|}^p {\chi}_{\{n\}})(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
{|f(x)|}^p & \mbox{si} & x \in \{n\}\mbox{;}
\\
0 & \mbox{si} & x \notin \{n\}\mbox{;}
\end{array}
\right\} = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
{|f(n)|}^p & \mbox{si} & x = n\mbox{;}
\\
0 & \mbox{si} & x \neq n\mbox{,}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
because of this
$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}} \left({|f|}^p {\chi}_{\{n\}}\right) d \mu = {|f(n)|}^p \mu(\{n\}) + 0 \cdot \mu({\{n\}}^c) = {|f(n)|}^p \mu(\{n\}) + 0 = {|f(n)|}^p \mu(\{n\}) = {|f(n)|}^p\mbox{.}
$$
Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}} {|f|}^p d \mu = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{N}} \left({|f|}^p {\chi}_{\{n\}}\right) d \mu = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {|f(n)|}^p = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {|a_n|}^p\mbox{.}
$$
Finally,
$$
L^p = \left\{f : X \to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ (or } \mathbb{C}\mbox{)}, \int_X {|f|}^p d \mu < \infty\right\} = \left\{{\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty} : \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {|a_n|}^p < \infty\right\} = {\ell}^p\mbox{.}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
M_0 = \{f : X \to \Bbb {C} \,:\, \forall \epsilon >0 : \mu (\{x : |f (x)| > \epsilon\}) <\infty \}
$$
and
$$
M = \{f \,:\, \exists c \in \Bbb {R }, g \in M_0 : f = c + g\}.
$$
If we specialise to the counting measure, we have $M_0 = c_0$ and $M = c $.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, only that. I will be working in the proof of that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually $c_0$ and $c$ are more like $C_0(X)$ and $C(X)$ for a suitable space $X$. In fact, take $X=\{\frac{1}{n}| n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. We can see easily that $C(X)=c$. Similarly $C_0(X)$ can be seen as functions vanishing at $0$ (or $\infty$ by taking $X=\mathbb{N}$).